# FastAPI Automatically Rounds-off Decimal Values in Response

Tags: python, decimal, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Pydantic-based Response Model with a Decimal in FastAPI-based app. I want to return a response with precision up to 20 decimal values. But after serialization, it rounds off the decimal of 15 digits to 14 digits.

For example:

```
Original Decimal    : 328.448267489936666
Decimal in Response : 328.44826748993665
```

I have tried setting `getcontext.prec = 15`, but it has no effect on it.

Minimal reproducible Example :

```
from decimal import getcontent, Decimal
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Dict

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root()->Dict[str, Decimal]:
    getcontext().prec = 15 
    return {"a": Decimal(328.448267489936666)}
```

Dependencies :
fastapi==0.92.0

uvicorn==0.20.0

pydantic==1.10.5

Python 3.7

Comment: Some precision loss happens with `Decimal(328.448267489936666)` since that's a float – try `Decimal("328.448267489936666")` so you have a precise `Decimal` to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some precision loss happens with `Decimal(328.448267489936666)` since you're converting a float to a Decimal – convert a string to a Decimal with `Decimal("328.448267489936666")` so you have a precise `Decimal` to begin with, and then:

```
import decimal
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Dict

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root() -> Dict[str, decimal.Decimal]:
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 15
    return {"a": decimal.Decimal("328.448267489936666")}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, port=11111)
```

```
~ $ curl http://localhost:11111
{"a":"328.448267489936666"}
```

Note how the Decimal is a string in the JSON; that's because many JSON decoders just use floats for number content (at least by default), and that can't be trusted to be precise either.

The serialization behavior actually seems to depend on the version of Pydantic in use; Pydantic 2.x encodes decimals as strings, while Pydantic 1 doesn't.

You can patch the encoder dict in FastAPI to fix this though; do something like this early enough in your app (or in a startup hook):

```
from fastapi import encoders
encoders.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[decimal.Decimal] = str
```

Comment: "many JSON decoders just use floats for number content" specifically double-precision floating-point numbers (colloquially "doubles"), which is also [what's recommended by RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6). Also relevant is that not all JSON APIs provide hooks which run during parsing, Python does (so you can ask for "floats" to be parsed as decimals), but browser-JS does not (the reviver runs on converted types, so even if you include decimal.js it's too late, you need to add a bespoke json parser as well)

Comment: @akx  Even when we use string to initialize decimal.Decimal("328.448267489936666"), there is still some precision loss. 
We get the response  {"a":328.44826748993665}

Comment: @KeshavMishra Right, this seems to depend on the version of Pydantic you're using – 2.x defaults to strings for decimals. Augmented my answer.